# Restriction method for producing ANOVA - set-to-zero vs. sum-to-zero

Tags: r, statistics, lm, anova, restriction

So I have a question regarding the type of restriction the method uses to obtain a solution to the normal equation. I'm wondering how the set-to-zero and sum-to-zero restriction produces the same sum of squares, mean squares, and F vale from the anova and lsmeans and standard errors. The example below shows how I change the restriction. Can anyone explain why this equivalence occurs and why it is important?

```
library(car); library(emmeans); library(multcomp);
y <- c(20,25,26,22,25,25,26,27,22,31)
Y <- matrix(y, nrow = 10)
t <- factor(c(rep(1,6), rep(2,4)))
b <- factor(c(1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3))
Trt <- interaction(t,b)
data <- data.frame(Y, t, b, Trt)

options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
fit.sum <- lm(Y ~ t + b + t*b, data = data)
summary(fit.sum)

options(contrasts=c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
fit.set <- lm(Y ~ t + b + t*b, data = data)
summary(fit.set)

#produced statement from both#

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   20.000      1.323  15.119 0.000112 ***
t2             6.500      1.620   4.012 0.015972 *  
b2             5.500      1.620   3.395 0.027412 *  
b3             4.000      1.528   2.619 0.058885 .  
t2:b2        -10.000      2.291  -4.364 0.012021 *  
t2:b3          0.500      2.227   0.225 0.833338    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.323 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9176,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8145 
F-statistic: 8.903 on 5 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.0273


Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  24.8333     0.4590  54.107 6.98e-07 ***
t1           -1.6667     0.4590  -3.631  0.02213 *  
b1           -1.5833     0.6553  -2.416  0.07306 .  
b2           -1.0833     0.6553  -1.653  0.17363    
t1:b1        -1.5833     0.6553  -2.416  0.07306 .  
t1:b2         3.4167     0.6553   5.214  0.00645 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.323 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9176,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8145 
F-statistic: 8.903 on 5 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.02733
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the lines below is the same for the sum and set-to-zero contrasts because in each case they are the projection of Y onto the space spanned by the columns of the model matrix associated with the right hand side. The two sets of contrasts merely change the coordinates but do not change the spaces spanned.

```
fit1 <- fitted(lm(Y ~ 1, data))
fit2 <- fitted(lm(Y ~ t, data))
fit3 <- fitted(lm(Y ~ t + b, data))
fit4 <- fitted(lm(Y ~ t + b + t*b, data))
```

Now the sums of squares only depend on the above fitted values.  For example the sum of squares for b is

```
crossprod(fit3 - fit2)
```

Thus the sum of squares cannot differ.

Also the dimensions of the spaces are not affected by the contrasts so the mean squares must be the same too as the mean squares are just the sum of squares divided by the dimensions of the spaces spanned.

The F ratio only depends on the above quantities so it cannot be different either.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to think about this is the fact that no matter what parameterization is used, the fitted values are the same. And the sums of squares can be expressed in terms of the fitted values.

Regarding estimated marginal means (lsmeans), those could be different with different parameterizations. However, the **emmeans** package performs an estimability check (at least for most models) and will not display emmeans that are not uniquely estimable. (And, to tie these ideas together, uniquely estimable parameters are exactly defined as those that are expressible in terms of the fitted values.)